# Converting a Distance string into a Number

Tags: javascript, parsing

When using the Google API for calculating the distance between two location, it returns me the distance in string format.

For example: 1,585 KM, 54 KM etc.

I want it to be converted to a number. What is the best way to convert a string like **1,525 KM** into a number like **1525**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the [Google Maps Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/), there is another field in the `distance` object called `value` that has a Number value. As documented in the API, the units is metres.

But to answer your original question, I would remove all non-digit characters from the string using a regular expression:

```
var dist = '1,525 KM';
dist = Number(dist.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''));
```

Comment: What happens when it is `1,524.2 KM` (using `,` as the decimal mark and `.` as the decimal point) or `1.524,2 KM` (using `.` as the decimal mark and `,` as the decimal point)?

Answer (score 2):

Strongly recommend to use distance `value` instead of the text. Because it can be `.` format also example `1.525 KM`.

Hence as [@rink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404623/rink-attendant-6) says use value which will be always in `meters` and you can convert the same to your format which is a cleaner solution according to my opinion

```
valueInKm = value * 0.001
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `,` or `.` as the decimal mark and you can have decimal points then you can use something like this to return a struct in the format `{ value: Number, units: String }`:

```
function getDistance( dist ){
  var match = /^([+-]?[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:(?:([,.])(?:\d{3}\2)*\d{3}(?:(?!\2)[,.]\d+)?)|[,.]\d+)?|[+-]?0(?:[,.]\d+)?) (.+)$/
    .exec( dist );
  if ( match ){
     return {
       value: parseFloat( match[1].split( match[2] ).join( '' ).replace( ',', '.' ), 10 ),
       units: match[3]
     };
  }
  return { value: null, units: null };
}
```

**Testing:**

```
var results = [
  { in: "0 m", dist: 0, units: "m" },
  { in: "10 m", dist: 10, units: "m" },
  { in: "0.2 m", dist: 0.2, units: "m" },
  { in: "0,2 m", dist: 0.2, units: "m" },
  { in: "1,202 m", dist: 1202, units: "m" },
  { in: "1,524.2 KM", dist: 1524.2, units: "KM" },
  { in: "1.524,2 KM", dist: 1524.2, units: "KM" },
  { in: "9,234,524.2 KM", dist: 9234524.2, units: "KM" },
  { in: "9.234.524,2 KM", dist: 9234524.2, units: "KM" },
];

var successes = 0;
for ( var i = 0; i < results.length; i++ ){
  var v = getDistance( results[i].in );
  if ( v.value == results[i].dist && v.units == results[i].units )
    successes++
  else
    console.log( results[i].in, v.value, v.units );
}
console.log( "Successes:", successes, "Failures:", results.length - successes );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `parseInt` , `.replace()` with `RegExp` `/[^\d+]/` to replace characters that are not digits within input text

```js
var text = "1,525 KM";

var n = parseInt(text.replace(/[^\d+]/g, ""));

console.log(n);
```

Comment: `var text = "1,234,567,890 KM";` outputs `1234`